# Tableau CRM: How to resolve scoring error in model manager

Tags: einstein-analytics, tableau-crm

I created a story and model after a recipe ran successfully.   When I click "Score Data" in Model Manager for that model it ran with some success and error.  I want to see/know the errors. How and where to check those errors? How to fix them ?
[image]